# passing an argument to anon function inside array - returning output with console.log

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

Here is the simple codeschool javascript math problem.

I need help with iteration through array with array method - map(). How can I return (with console.log) results of every array cell?
What is the best way to pass, for example, some number as parameter of anonymous function (a). Thanks for any help you can provide...

```
var puzzlers = [
    function (a) { return 3 * a - 8;},
    function (a) { return (a+2) * (a+2) * (a+2);},
    function (a) { return (Math.pow(a,2) - 9);},
    function (a) { return a % 4;}
];
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(puzzlers[n](value));`? This should execute the function at the given index, unless I've misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a foreach using eval :

```
for ( var puzzle in puzzlers )
{
    var a = puzzlers[puzzle](10);
    console.log( a );
}
```

foreach will work like an iterator calling next automaticaly
@edit -- you dont need eval;

Comment: you don't need `eval`, look at comment by @ninty9notout

Comment: I'd also like to share that the `for(var ... in ....)` pattern is *really* slow compared to `for(var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++)` pattern. See here http://jsperf.com/for-in-or-for

Comment: Its slower but think about the values, if you have declared the indexes, like [0][1][3] your iteratior with for wont work poperly, that its an GENERAL solution

Comment: If you have an array with skipped indices, something is wrong with the design in the first place. Arrays are not maps, they are an ordered lists of items.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
 array[indexOffunction](parameterToPass)...
```

Here is solution:

```
var puzzlers = [
  function ( a ) { return 8*a - 10; }, 
  function ( a ) { return (a-3) * (a-3) * (a-3); }, 
  function ( a ) { return a * a + 4; },
  function ( a ) { return a % 5; }
];

alert(puzzlers[puzzlers[1](3)](puzzlers[3](9)));
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using self executing functions, like this :

```
var a = 5;
var puzzlers = [ 
    ( function (a) { return 3 * a - 8;} )(a),
    ( function (a) { return (a+2) * (a+2) * (a+2) } )(a),
    ( function (a) { return (Math.pow(a,2) - 9);} )(a),
    ( function (a) { return a % 4;} )(a),
];

console.log(puzzlers);
// OUTPUT:
// [7, 343, 16, 1]
```

Comment: thanks, i'll consider it! the answer of codeschool problem was var puzzlers array, the iteration through array was problem I asked myself :)